# How to make the cells higher so the text would go on multiple lines and make the table more narrow

Tags: tables, tabulary

```
\begin{table} [H]
\begin{adjustbox}{width=0.5\textwidth , center}
\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{>{\raggedright}p{3cm}LLL}\\\toprule
  Vindhastighed (m/s) & Produktion (kW) & Turbinens effektivitet (\%) \\\midrule
    0 & 0 & 0 \\\hline
    1 & 0 & 0 \\\hline
    2 & 0 & 0 \\\hline
    3 & 0 & 0 \\\hline
    4 & 161 & 39 \\\hline
    5 & 351 & 43 \\\hline
    6 & 635 & 45 \\\hline
    7 & 1026 & 46 \\\hline
    9 & 2204 & 47 \\\hline
    10 & 2910 & 45 \\\hline
    11 & 3399 & 39 \\\hline
    12 & 3567 & 32 \\\hline
    13 & 3596 & 25 \\\hline
    14 & 3600 & 20 \\\hline
    15 & 3600 & 16 \\\hline
    16 & 3600 & 14 \\\hline
    17 & 3600 & 11 \\\hline
    18 & 3600 & 10 \\\hline
    19 & 3600 & 8 \\\hline
    20 & 3600 & 7 \\\hline
    21 & 3600 & 6 \\\hline
    22 & 3600 & 5 \\\hline
    23 & 3600 & 5 \\\hline
    24 & 3600 & 4 \\\hline
    25 & 3600 & 4 \\\bottomrule
\end{tabulary}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Please give us a compilable code and explain a bit more, what you want to do. Where do you want to have more lines and why? And how narrow do you need? Why do you use `adjustbox` and `tabulary`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got you right, you might be looking for something like this?

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{microtype}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{per-mode=symbol-or-fraction}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{S[table-format=1.0]S[table-format=4.0]S[table-format=2.0]}\\
        \toprule
        \multicolumn{1}{L{1.8cm}}{Vindhastighed (\si{\metre\per\second})} & \multicolumn{1}{L{1.7cm}}{Produktion (\si{\kilo\watt})} & \multicolumn{1}{L{2.3cm}}{Turbinens effektivitet (\si{\percent})} \\
        \midrule
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        2 & 0 & 0 \\
        3 & 0 & 0 \\
        4 & 161 & 39 \\
        5 & 351 & 43 \\
        6 & 635 & 45 \\
        7 & 1026 & 46 \\
        9 & 2204 & 47 \\
        10 & 2910 & 45 \\
        11 & 3399 & 39 \\
        12 & 3567 & 32 \\
        13 & 3596 & 25 \\
        14 & 3600 & 20 \\
        15 & 3600 & 16 \\
        16 & 3600 & 14 \\
        17 & 3600 & 11 \\
        18 & 3600 & 10 \\
        19 & 3600 & 8 \\
        20 & 3600 & 7 \\
        21 & 3600 & 6 \\
        22 & 3600 & 5 \\
        23 & 3600 & 5 \\
        24 & 3600 & 4 \\
        25 & 3600 & 4 \\\bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly, sorry if the questions wasn't really clear

Comment: @MathiasAndersen Glad I could help, nevertheless.